# Notification not always starting the Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Per title, it doesn't always start the activity.
There's no error in output log, it just says

> 06-01 16:46:36.924: I/ActivityManager(370): START u0 {flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.myapp/md527315440e30c82eb86ffbe7caee6cb98.MyView
>   bnds=[96,712][1056,840] (has extras)} from pid -1

What I mean by "not always" is this:

1. I start app, it shows the main screen. Notification is received, I tap on notification, activity is run. App navigates to a different activity, and this activity is closed (finish() is called).
2. Next, I tap on back button until app is closed. Notification is received, I tap on notification, activity is run. App navigates to a different activity, and this activity is closed (finish() is called).
3. Next, keeping app in same state (no navigation). Notification is received, I tap on notification, activity is NOT run.

Here's the code which is adding a notification:

```
    void CreateNotification (Context context, PushNotification pn)
    {
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (context)
            .SetContentTitle (pn.Title)
            .SetContentText (pn.Body)
            .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.launcher)
            .SetLargeIcon (Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource (context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.launcher))
            .SetSound (Android.Provider.Settings.System.DefaultNotificationUri)
            .SetAutoCancel (true);

        Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(context);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(LoginView)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(GetIntent());

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = context.GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
    }

    static Intent GetIntent ()
    {
        // returns an intent
    }
```

I saw other questions with the same issue but no solution works.
If someone can give some hints or ideas as why this might not work.

Comment: why vote down my question? not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Setting up a regular activity PendingIntent" section of the [android notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). You are not following the guidelines laid out in the example. Particularly, you don't do the following:

> Create a back stack based on the Intent that starts the Activity:
>   Create the Intent to start the Activity. Create a stack builder by
>   calling TaskStackBuilder.create(). Add the back stack to the stack
>   builder by calling addParentStack(). For each Activity in the
>   hierarchy you've defined in the manifest, the back stack contains an
>   Intent object that starts the Activity. This method also adds flags
>   that start the stack in a fresh task. Note: Although the argument to
>   addParentStack() is a reference to the started Activity, the method
>   call doesn't add the Intent that starts the Activity. Instead, that's
>   taken care of in the next step.
>
> Add the Intent that starts the Activity from the notification, by
>   calling addNextIntent(). Pass the Intent you created in the first step
>   as the argument to addNextIntent(). If you need to, add arguments to
>   Intent objects on the stack by calling
>   TaskStackBuilder.editIntentAt(). This is sometimes necessary to ensure
>   that the target Activity displays meaningful data when the user
>   navigates to it using Back. Get a PendingIntent for this back stack by
>   calling getPendingIntent(). You can then use this PendingIntent as the
>   argument to setContentIntent().

Sorry about the formatting. I'm unsure how to preserve the original from the site.

Comment: thanks. I actually tried that too. I will redo that and edit post again. Btw, did you vote down the question? May I ask why?

Comment: @AndreiN. No, I did not downvote it. I'll add an upvote.

Comment: Hmm, using PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.OneShot fixed the issue.

Comment: @AndreiN. that's good to know. I thought the flag might be an issue, but when I looked at the description, I didn't see anything that suggested to me the flag you were using wouldn't work.